# Update state in reducer for search function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm trying to create a search function to update the state in the store, but the reducer actually ads to the state the filtered results once I stop searching. So I endup having duplicated.

When the search input is empty, I dispatch the initial fetch but the filtered result is added to the state.

this is my reducer

```
    switch(action.type){
        case GET_ENTRIES:
            return [ ...state, ...action.entries ]   
        case SEARCH_ENTRIES:      
            return [...action.entries]
         default:        
             return state
    }
```

my action

```
export const searchHandle = (query) => (dispatch, getState) => {
    const theState = getState()    
    const entries = theState.entriesData.filter(val => (
        val.firstName.includes(query) ||
        val.lastName.includes(query)  ||
        val.phoneNumber.includes(query)
    ))    
    dispatch({ 
        type:SEARCH_ENTRIES, 
        entries
    })        
}
```

and the handler

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
        e.target.value.length > 0 ? dispatch(searchHandle(e.target.value))
        : dispatch(entriesCall())
    }
```

Comment: It is probably better to only store the filter term in the store and use a selector to filter the entries in the `mapStateToProps`. Have a look at this example from [re-select](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect#example). If you filter the times in the store directly you either lose the filtered items or you have to duplicate them leaving you with lots of data that can get out of sync violating the single source of truth priciple.

Comment: Apart from that I don't see a reason in your code that explains the observed behaviour. How do you pass the state to your component?

Comment: with the useSelector hook